# Play: how to append a list to an existing JSON variable?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Given the following json variable

```
   var json: JsValue = JsObject(Seq(
      "retcode" -> JsString("1")
    ))
```

and the following Writes object for a `User` class

```
implicit val w2 : Writes[User] = (
      (JsPath \ "id").write[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "userid").write[String] and
      (JsPath \ "name").write[String]
  ) (unlift(User.unapply))
```

Assuming I have a list of users

```
var list : List[User] = ( some list )
```

How to append the list to the initial `json` var?

Comment: `JsObject` provides a `+ (name, jsValue)` operation (but take care as using a `var` is already "un-functional").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to end up with something like this (the users list added as another key/value to your original object):

```
{
  "retcode" : "1",
  "users" : [ {
    "id" : "1",
    "userid" : "u1",
    "name" : "Bob"
  }, {
    "id" : "2",
    "userid" : "u2",
    "name" : "Fred"
  } ]
}
```

you can do:

```
val newJson = json.as[JsObject] + ("users" -> Json.toJson(list))
```

You can skip the `.as[JsObject]` if you declare `json` as a `JsObject` to start with, rather than a `JsValue`. (The `as` is potentially unsafe if you don't know your JSON definitely represents an object, as opposed to a list or a primitive. See [using validation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJson#Using-validation) for a better way to handle that.)

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose we need to add / append json to existing one.

Consider

```
userAddressList = Users multiple address list.
```

Now you want to append above two info into single json object:

```
val res = JsObject(Seq(
("userAddresses", Json.toJson(userAddressList)),
("userDetails", Json.toJson(userService.getUserDtlsByID(userId)))
))
```

It will produce result like below:

```
{
"userAddresses" :[{"addId":"001"},{"addId":"002"}],
"userDetails":{"id":"001", "name":"MAC", "designation":"Manager"}
}
```

I hope this will work ;-)